# Open Activity on Notification Click - Intent flag issue

Tags: android, android-intent, flags

I am creating an Android app. I have set up the notification system to open a specific activity/class on notification click. When my App is totally closed and I send a notification and when I click on it opens the correct activity like this example:

App is not running > Notification comes in > Click on the notification > Activity_T opens.

BUT, when my app is running and I get a notification and when I click on it to open the Activity_T it doesn't it loads MainActivity instead.

The flags I use are the follow

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, (Class<?>) activityToLaunch);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    intent.putExtra("tt", title);
    intent.putExtra("bd", body);
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

I want to open Activity_T on notification click either the app is running or not. How to force open Activity_T whenever I click on the notification.

Comment: Can you post the manifest? or some activity tag code

Comment: @jiteshmohite if you are referring to know the launch mode of the Activity_T it is android:launchMode="singleTask" and for Mainactivity there is no launchmode set

Comment: try this, intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

Comment: @jiteshmohite thank you, I have just tried it but didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Remove singleTask from menifest and see.

Comment: @jiteshmohite It is still happening. I wonder why

Comment: Now simple, Just override methods like onStop and onDestroy() in your suspected activities. and put debug points or logs in it, You will come to how things are going. I am sure you will get something by debugging.

Comment: Please post your manifest in the question so that we can see all of it.

Comment: You also should not use special launch modes like `singleTask` or `singleInstance`. These create more problems than they solve.

Answer (score 1):

I send notification from receiver onReceive method. When click on notification,I open an activity,even the app was killed. I used like that

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.my_ic)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(msg)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
```